# Testing Remedy-on-Demand REST API code

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am writing a python module to interact to the ROD (remedy on demand) BMC ticketing product. So far I have only written the log in and log out methods and tests. Before I crack on with the more complex methods I hope someone can review the current test strategy and happy to hear any suggestions for improvements.

**rodAPI.py**

```py
import requests


class RodApi:
    def __init__(self, fqdn, username, password, token_type="AR-JWT"):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.fqdn = fqdn
        self.token_type = token_type
        self.login_url = f"https://{fqdn}/api/jwt/login"
        self.logout_url = f"https://{fqdn}/api/jwt/logout"
        self.token = None

    def login(self) -> bool:
        data = {"username": self.username, "password": self.password}
        headers = {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        response = requests.post(self.login_url, data=data, headers=headers)

        print(f"connecting to URL: {self.login_url}")
        print(f"https status code: {response.status_code}")
        self.token = response.text
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return True
        return False

    def logout(self) -> bool:
        headers = {"Authorization": f"{self.token_type} {self.token}"}
        response = requests.post(self.logout_url, headers=headers)

        print(f"connecting to URL: {self.logout_url}")
        print(f"https status code: {response.status_code}")
        if response.status_code == 204:
            print(f"Logged out with a status of: {response.status_code}")
            return True
        else:
            print(f"Error logging out: {response.text}")
            return False
```

**test_rodAPI**

````py
import pytest

from rodAPI import RodApi


@pytest.fixture()
def rod_api_instance():
    rod_api = RodApi("example.com", "some_user", "some_password")
    return rod_api


@pytest.fixture()
def rod_api_logged_in_instance(responses, rod_api_instance):
    responses.add(responses.POST, rod_api_instance.login_url, body="some_token_string")
    rod_api_instance.login()
    return rod_api_instance


def test_login_success(responses, rod_api_instance: RodApi):
    responses.add(responses.POST, rod_api_instance.login_url, body="some_token_string")
    result = rod_api_instance.login()
    assert result is True
    assert rod_api_instance.token == "some_token_string"


def test_login_fail(responses, rod_api_instance: RodApi):
    responses.add(responses.POST, rod_api_instance.login_url, status=404)
    result = rod_api_instance.login()
    assert result is False


def test_logout_success(responses, rod_api_logged_in_instance: RodApi):
    responses.add(responses.POST, rod_api_logged_in_instance.logout_url, status=204)
    result = rod_api_logged_in_instance.logout()
    assert result is True


def test_logout_fail(responses, rod_api_logged_in_instance: RodApi):
    responses.add(responses.POST, rod_api_logged_in_instance.logout_url, status=404)
    result = rod_api_logged_in_instance.logout()
    assert result is False
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Redundant headers

Read
https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L514 - your use of

```
    headers = {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
```

should not be needed.

### Out-of-order progress

You print

```
    print(f"connecting to URL: {self.login_url}")
```

when this has already happened. Either say "connected to", or move this statement before your `post`.

### Exception degradation

Resist the urge to sabotage the Python exception system. Rather than returning booleans from your methods, call `response.raise_for_status`, and optionally wrap that in a `try/except/raise MyException() from e` with your own exception type. `raise_for_status` will also obviate your status code checks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I wasnt aware of raise for status, I have taken all your feedback and incorporated it into my code and testing strategy.